# Need Get HttpPost Values in TextBox Control Unsing ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to pass data between pages using ASP.NET C#, I need to get text value from first page to second page inside a TextBox using HttPost. My pages structure is given below
I have Two(2) pages as given below:

### WebForm1.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtData" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnHttpPost" runat="server" Text="HTTPPost" PostBackUrl="~/WebForm2.aspx" />
    </div>
</form>
```

### WebForm2.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h1>HttpPost</h1>
        Data is: <%=Request.Form["txtData"] %>
        <p>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtGetValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

> As we see in WebForm2.aspx the line below Heading 1 Tag working fine, but I need the value of the previous page (WebForm1.aspx) in TextBox named (txtGetValue)  available in second page (Webform2.aspx).

Comment: One line in code behind's Page_Load should do it. Have you tried that?

Comment: No, Please guide me and type that line. Will be very very thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be really easily done in code behind. Like so:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtGatValue.Text = Request.Form["txtData"];
}
```